# I want to replace null value to string and change the decimal points in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display user's data in table.
but I want to show the null value as '-' and only shows 2decimal points. ex)2.18,1.29
I was trying to use forEach like this

```
forEach((x)=>{
 if(x.age===null){
    x.age='-'
 }
})
```

but this code is not useful because I always needs to put x.age or x.extrapoint ,
so my Idea is replace all the value in object..

```
const user = [
    { name: 'jenny', age: null, points: 56.9987,extraPoint:null },
    { name: 'david', age: 56, points: 56.324355,extraPoint:8 },
    { name: 'dude', age: null, points: 20.9987,extraPoint:null }
];
```

output should be

```
'jenny', '-', 56.9
'david', 56, 56.3,
'dude', '-',20.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to using the map function as below:

```js
user = user.map((x)=>{
 if(!x.age){
    x.age = '-'
 }

 return x;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map with a check for the values.

```js
const
    replaceNull = v => v === null ? '-': v
    user = [{ name: 'jenny', age: null, points: 56.9987, extraPoint: null }, { name: 'david', age: 56, points: 56.324355, extraPoint: 8 }, { name: 'dude', age: null, points: 20.9987, extraPoint: null }],
    result = user.map(o => [
        replaceNull(o.name),
        replaceNull(o.age),
        o.points === null ? '-' : o.points.toFixed(2),
    ]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `map` function, like this:

```js
const user = [
    { name: 'jenny', age: null, points: 56.9987,extraPoint:null },
    { name: 'david', age: 56, points: 56.324355,extraPoint:8 },
    { name: 'dude', age: null, points: 20.9987,extraPoint:null }
];

var output = user.map(x => ({ name: x.name, age: x.age || '-', points: x.points.toFixed(2)}));

console.log(output);
```

---

**Update:**

If you want the number *exactly* (like `56.9` `56.3` `20.9`), you can try to convert the number to a string and split it:

```js
const user = [
    { name: 'jenny', age: null, points: 56.9987,extraPoint:null },
    { name: 'david', age: 56, points: 56.324355,extraPoint:8 },
    { name: 'dude', age: null, points: 20.9987,extraPoint:null }
];

var output = user.map(x => [x.name, x.age || '-', Number(x.points.toString().slice(0, 4))]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: but I dont want to make x.name or x.age because if I get more data then I need to code again and again like x.something, x.someNew... so is there's any way that I can just change all the value from object?

Comment: @jenny I've updated my answer, you can try again with my 2nd solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```js
const user = [
    { name: 'jenny', age: null, points: 56.9987,extraPoint:null },
    { name: 'david', age: 56, points: 56.324355,extraPoint:8 },
    { name: 'dude', age: null, points: 20.9987,extraPoint:null }
];

for (const ind of Object.keys(user))
  console.log(`${user[ind].name}, ${user[ind].age || '-'}, ${user[ind].points.toFixed(2)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to dynamically enumerate and loop over object properties, you won't need to reference any of the properties in your code by name

```js
const user = [
    { name: 'jenny', age: null, points: 56.9987,extraPoint:null },
    { name: 'david', age: 56, points: 56.324355,extraPoint:8 },
    { name: 'dude', age: null, points: 20.9987,extraPoint:null }
];

for(var i=0;i<user.length;i++){
    let temp = {};
  
    for (var key of Object.keys(user[i])) {
        temp[key] = user[i][key]  || '-'
    }
    user[i] = temp;
}

console.log(user);
```